# AngularJS ng-bind is not updating

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-services, ng-bind

```
<div class="btn-group dd-rm-action" role="group" aria-label="...">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dd-action pagination-centered" ng-click="Save()">Save</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default dd-action dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownState" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true" ng-bind="rmCW.State.Name">
        <b class="caret"></b>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownState">
        <li role="presentation" ng-repeat="task in docState.Tasks">
            <a role="menuitem" tabindex="{{$index}}" href="#" ng-click="execTask(task)">{{task.Name}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have an angularjs application witch works fine just that the `ng-bind` for the button does not update once I update the scope value:

```
result.then(function (r) {
    $scope.$emit('UNLOAD');
    if (r.status == 0) {
        var cs = JSON.parse(r.data)
        $scope.docState = cs;
        $scope.rmCW.Current = cs;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably because of `ng-bind="rmCW.State.Name"` and your scope is set to other property.

```
 $scope.rmCW.Current = cs;
```

Either you need to set ng-bind to `ng-bind="rCW.Current.Name"`, or you need to set the $scope as `$scope.rmCW.State = cs;`

Comment: Ty I better go to sleep :)